# Array of 2-D array C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

Can we define an array of 2D array in C# of this manner? 
Or any alternate approach to obtain similar dataset?

```
double[][,] testArray = new double[a][b,c];
```

Note: All the three indices - a,b and c are obtained in runtime.

Thanks

Comment: You can only declare one array dimension at a time.  `new double[a][,]` is valid, while your declaration is not.  You can then loop across the outer dimension to populate the inner arrays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it, but you have to initialize each 2D array separately :

```
double[][,] testArray = new double[a][,];
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
    testArray[i] = new double[b, c];
}
```

---

Another way is to just declare a 3D array:

```
double[,,] testArray3D = new double[a, b, c];
```

That is, you can make that change if every 2D array you wanted in the beginning is to have the same dimensions

Answer (score 4):

Sure.

```
int[][,] arrayOf2DArrays = 
{
    new int[,] {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}},
    new int[,] {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}},
    new int[,] {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}}
};
```

This is essentially a one-dimensional jagged array that contains three two-dimensional arrays, each of different size.

The elements can be accessed in the following manner:

```
var element = arrayOf2DArrays[0][0, 0]; // etc
Console.WriteLine(element);
```

..and `arrayOf2DArrays.Length` will, in the example above, return `3`, as `arrayOf2DArrays` contains three two-dimensional arrays.

> [Jagged Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) - MSDN